# Is the Django-cms addon, Aldryn news/blog; extensible?

Tags: django, blogs, placeholder, django-cms

I am using Django-cms to create a blog. In order to create the blog posts themselves, I am trying Aldryn news/blog.

My question is, is there a way to add additional fields to the template for this particular addon?

[<< Default news/blog template layout image >>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IetN.png)

What I am trying to do is to split each post into elements, which will be common across most/all posts for a given category.

Then I could call each posts "elements" as such:

```
{% if placeholder "contentElement_1" %}
<some styling>
    {% placeholder "contentElement_1" %}
</some styling>
{% endif %}

<some Style></>

{% if placeholder "contentElement_2" %}
<some styling>
        {% placeholder "contentElement_2" %}
</some styling>
{% endif %}

<some Style></>
```

etc...

With this I have flexibility with regard to ad placement, accordions, cards and other styling within the html template, in and around the post elements.

As I see it, with "Aldryn news/blog" I get one (% placeholder "content" %}, a title, and that's it.

What Ive tried, future considerations:

I'm assuming what I am looking for would create additional database fields for each "content element" as well. Which I would like for a later date to possibly be able to call for particular elements of any post within filtered search results or other aggregator type functions.

That previous paragraph is not a show stopper at this point, I want this blog up and running soon; but it would be ideal future consideration.

Being newer to django and django-cms, but somewhat familiar with python; I have spent only a short time messing with placeholders. However, it seems as though I can only add global placeholders to the blog pages anyways; and not post specific ones.

Suggestions:

Alternately, if this particular addon is not the answer, any suggestions to achieve this model would be appreciated.

Extra Info for context:

I am using a tutorial at http://support.divio.com/en/collections/69450-academy#guide-how-to-build-a-website-and-blog-with-django-cms ; as a basis for my initial work.

However I am using Foundation instead of bootstrap, and possibly adding Redis or neo4j to the app in the near term, to both support a future social element, and I am theorizing that I might have more flexibility and simplification of queries in the future with a graph or multi database than an SQL in pursuing this "individual post elements" idea among others.

Aldryn is a Divio.com product. (The old company name). The docs are here >>
https://aldryn-newsblog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Thanks in advance for any feedback!